# Proving an inequality in a normed space

Tags: inequality

Let $E$ be a normed space and prove or disprove the following inequality:
$\Vert x \Vert^a\Vert y \Vert ^b \leq \Vert x \Vert ^{a+b}+\Vert y \Vert ^{a+b}$ for any $a,b \geq 0$ and any $x,y\in E$.

I have tried inserting different values into the expression and couldn't disprove it. So I'm assuming it's true, but I do not have any idea of how to prove it. Where do I start?

Comment: If $$0 \leq t \leq s$$ then $$t^{a}s^{b} \leq s^{a}s^{b}=s^{a+b}\leq t^{a+b}+s^{a+b}.$$ Similarly, $t^{a}s^{b} \leq  s^{a+b}+s^{a+b}$ when  $0 \leq s <t$. Put $t=\|x\|$ and $s=\|y\|$.

Comment: (As we see from the comment above) this has nothing to do with normed spaces, it's just an inequality for positive reals.

Answer (score 1):

It's true.  Let $m=\rm{max}(||x||,||y||)$.  WLOG let's say $m=||x||$.  Then $||x||^a||y||^b\le ||x||^a||x||^b=||x||^{a+b}\le||x||^{a+b}+||y||^{a+b}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\|x\|=k\|y\|,$ where $k\geq0.$

Thus, we need to prove that $$k^{a+b}-k^a+1\geq0.$$
Now, let $0\leq k<1$.

Thus, $$k^{a+b}-k^a+1=k^{a+b}+(1-k^a)\geq0.$$
Also, let $k\geq1.$

Thus, $$k^{a+b}-k^a+1=k^a(k^b-1)+1>0$$ and we are done!